# Group semi-duplicate sql results together

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm a total noob with this, so please that in mind :).

I have a MySQL tabel with the folowing data:

```
ID   START        END       UserID
1   2017-03-16  2017-03-30  0
2   2017-05-01  2017-08-31  0
3   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0
4   2017-03-31  2017-03-31  0
5   2017-03-09  2017-03-28  1
6   2017-03-09  2017-03-10  1
7   2017-03-09  2017-03-10  2
8   2017-03-09  2017-03-09  2
9   2017-03-10  2017-03-11  1
10  2017-03-10  2017-03-11  2
```

Now i use MySQL to find matches for Start & End colums:

```
SELECT t.* FROM dates t JOIN (SELECT Start, End, UserID, count(*) AS NumDuplicates FROM dates GROUP BY Start, End having NumDuplicates > 1) TSUM on t.Start = tsum.Start and t.End = tsum.End
```

And i print this with PHP using foreach and echo. and get this result:

```
ID   START        END       UserID
6   2017-03-09  2017-03-10  1
7   2017-03-09  2017-03-10  2
9   2017-03-10  2017-03-11  1
10  2017-03-10  2017-03-11  2
```

Which is what i need.
In this result you can see that ID 6 & 7 are matches and 9 & 10 are.
What i now would need is a way to make this clear; seperate them in some way so that it is obvious that the matches are 6-7 and 9-10. A simple HR in between them would be enoug, or the matching lines in one row like this:

```
ID   START        END       UserID
6   2017-03-09  2017-03-10  1
7   2017-03-09  2017-03-10  2
<hr/>
9   2017-03-10  2017-03-11  1
10  2017-03-10  2017-03-11  2
```

or maybe like this:

```
ID   START        END       UserID
6 & 7   2017-03-09  2017-03-10  1 & 2
9 & 10  2017-03-10  2017-03-11  1 & 2
```

Any help would be much appreciated; Thanks !!!

Comment: sqlfiddle demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2b36/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code this will helps you.
That will give output as shown in 2nd Scenario

```
 SELECT t.Start, t.End,
       GROUP_CONCAT( t.ID SEPARATOR '&') AS ID,
       GROUP_CONCAT( t.UserID SEPARATOR '&') AS UserID
  FROM dates t 
  JOIN ( SELECT Start, End, UserID, COUNT(*) AS NumDuplicates 
           FROM dates
          GROUP BY Start, End 
         HAVING NumDuplicates > 1 ) AS TSUM
    ON t.Start = tsum.Start AND t.End = tsum.End
 GROUP BY Start, End
```

Comment: Hey Sagar; thank you; but this gives me 0 results :(